# Is there an east bloc analogue to Tom Clancy?

Tags: genre, tom-clancy

Tom Clancy wrote many speculative works on confrontation between the blocs during the Cold War, most notably the "Cold War gone hot" scenario Red Storm Rising, together with Larry Bond.

I'm wondering, were there any similar or analogous authors active in any country in the "East"?

Ideally, I'd like to find a "mirror work" to Red Storm Rising from the Warsaw Pact perspective, but I'd be interested in anything resembling the genre written in the east bloc. Barring that, any military techno-thriller written from a non-"Western" perspective would be interesting (regardless of era.)

Comment: A question this wide-ranging and speculative is one that ought to be translated into Esperanto and sent out into the whole world, ‘per flugiloj de facila vento’.